# Is there a way to tell Spring not to register a filter if the filter is declared as a Spring bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, filter

I'm building an application framework which (as part of the implementation) registers filters using Spring `FilterRegistrationBean` beans. The registration method (annotated with `@Bean`) returns either a `FilterRegistrationBean` wrapping the real filter, or a dummy `ServletContextInitializer`, according to some logic which determines whether the filter is turned on or off. (This way avoids cluttering up the filter chain with deactivated filters.)

```
// This method is in some other class which is an `@Component`, and not within the same class as the `Filter` itself
@Bean
public ServletContextInitializer register() {
    if (someLogic()) {
        Filter filter = new MyRealFilter();
        FilterRegistrationBean frb = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        // ... Stuff to do with configuring the filter patterns etc. ...
        return frb;
    } else {
        return new DummyServletContextInitializer(); // a SCI which does nothing
    }
}
```

Now, I want the filter to be context-aware. So I set the filter to be a `@Component`.

```
@Component
public class MyRealFilter implements Filter {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    // stuff
}
```

This works fine if the filter is turned on (`someLogic()` above returns true) and Spring still respects whatever configuration you specified on the `FilterRegistrationBean`. However, if the filter is turned off, the filter still gets registered because it is a `@Component`. It seems that Spring automatically registers any filter declared as a `@Component`, unless that filter was already registered in a `FilterRegistrationBean`.

Is there a way to tell Spring not to register a filter which is declared as an `@Component`? Or any other way to solve this problem where I want a filter to be context-aware but still be registered only via a `FilterRegistrationBean` and not directly?

**UPDATE:** I later found that actually the `@ApplicationContext` does not get autowired if I construct the bean myself within such a `register()` method. The way to get around this is to declare a subclass of `FilterRegistrationBean` as a `@Component` with a `@PostConstruct`, rather than using `register()`.

Comment: Your filter should be created only at runtime for the first time spring context is initialized?

Comment: Yes, the filter only needs to be created at init-time.

Comment: why don't you want to extend BeanFactoryPostProcessor and evaluate your logic branching between creating BeanDefinition or not. if your logic evaluates true, BeanDefinition should be created and registered within application-context. By the way, you don't need to mark your filter as @ Component to register it in spring container if you do this by hand (it's only an annotation-based way to register your bean to spring container).

Comment: Also one of the easiest way is to use NullFilter as implementation (wrap it to proxy called for instance "NullFilterProxy") and implement method "isNil()". So before you use it, you can check if (!filterBean.isNil()) { // use filter}. I am a little bit against custom Bean (Factory) PostProcessors because it is acting under-the-hood and it can be confusing. So i more prefer for NullObject concept if a bean is consider to be optional (So it helps to avoid some nasty @Autowired(required = false), painful profiles and tedious null-ifs) and is more readable and also can be used as default impl.

Comment: I think your second idea requires me to provide a dummy filter in the filter chain, which is exactly what I want to avoid as specified in my question. Regarding the first idea, I'm struggling to understand it. Do you mean I should replace my `register()` method with a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`? But then I wouldn't get the additional configuration advantages of a `FilterRegistrationBean`.

Comment: Do you understand that @Bean creates a BeanDefinition (proxy to your real instance) in the similar way it does with @Component? The main point of using @ Bean is to have an advanced logic in one convenient place and create specific "interface" implementation wrapped in bean (proxy) but you CAN'T skip it's creation so you must return some value (in worst case, it should be 'dummy' NullObject).

Comment: One of the way to avoid dummy (for some reason), you can create custom interface called Acceptable and implement it with "accept" method.  It should return aggregated value (instance value) generated at runtime. So, when you create your filter within FilterRegistrationBean, you should create it no matter what "someLogic" will be and set value "accept" to true or false according to your logic. Later on, PostProcessor should get this bean, check if it should be applied (through filter method "accept") and if it returns false (it depends how you create it), post processor should remove it from

Comment: context using BeanDefinitionRegistry#removeDefinition(..).

Comment: Register the filter conditionally that is what the `@ConditionalOn` stuff is for and you can extend it yourself with your own conditional expression.

Comment: @M.Deinum huh, didn't know that. Spring surprises me every time and provides convenient way to solve it! OP can use @Conditional(<...>) to register bean in ad-hoc manner. @ Conditional requires custom condition classes (i guess you can create it as a part of FilterRegistrationBean (like inner class)) and use your custom logic in this little "inner Condition subclass"

Comment: @Emusc: Regarding your first comment, yes I do understand that, but here the `@Bean` is a `ServletContextInitializer`, not the `Filter` itself. I am returning a dummy SCI, which doesn't impact the filter chain. Regarding your second(/third) comment, I actually thought the same as you simultaneously and tried to implement that. It works, but now I am facing a new problem that the `ApplicationContext` isn't `@Autowired` if I construct the filter myself. Regarding `@ConditionalOn`, I will look into that now to see if it can help.

Comment: @M.Deinum I looked into `@ConditionalOn` and I think this can help also, although it means I have to check the logic twice - once inside the `Condition` class and once inside the `register()` method. It doesn't solve my question in exactly the way I thought it would, because it only stops Spring from creating the bean, and doesn't allow it to not be registered as a filter. However now I'm facing a new problem that the `ApplicationContext` is not `@Autowired` even in this case. I wonder if switching to an `@Component` can help.....hmm, I may post a new question if there is no quick-fix here

Comment: ApplicationContext can be wired through ApplicationContextAware interface (your target class should implement it) and when post processor will read it, it will inject ApplicationContext instance for you.

Comment: @Emusc the *Aware interfaces are the "old way" of doing things and entirely equivalent to an autowired `ApplicationContext` in Spring 3+. The problem is that if I construct the bean then it is never seen by the bean factory post processor. That's why I'm wondering if using `@Component` rather than `@Bean` can help, and I'm looking into it now.

Comment: I've got it working now using `@Component`. But I still can't see how to get around running the logic twice - once for the `Filter` and once for the `FilterRegistrationBean`.

Comment: Finally got it working (!!) using a combination of the two approaches. I created a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` which checks for `Filter` beans which should have a corresponding `FilterRegistrationBean` but don't. Then I only need to put the `@Conditional` annotation on the `FilterRegistrationBean`. Thanks to both for your help. I have upvoted the comments which were particularly helpful.

Comment: Put all the the filter and filter registration bean definitions in a `@Configuration`  annotated class per filter as well as the `@Conditional` that way the configuration for that filter will be included only if the conditions match, no more repetition. No need to make it more complex then that... That is basically how Spring boot itself also does it :).

Comment: @M.Deinum Not sure what you mean. Does that mean I then have to go back to using `@Bean` rather than `@Component`? Then I won't be able to autowire things into the beans?

Comment: Yes you will. Define a `@Bean` for the filter and the filter registration and put the conditinal on the `@Configuratin` class those are in. This will give you multiple (small) `@Configuration` class, one per filter basically. Or you could create a large one with nested classes.

Comment: @M.Deinum I understand what you're saying, but as I mentioned, I won't be able to autowire the things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `@ConditionalOn` stuff to determine what needs to be registered. Instead of putting it on your filter or `@Bean` method do it on a `@Configuration` class.

```
@Configuration
public class OptionalWebFiltersConfiguration {

    @Configuration
    @ConditionalForFilterX
    public static class FilterXConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public Filter filterX() {
             return new FilterX();
        }

        @Bean
        public FilterRegistrationBean filterXRegistrationBean() {
             FilterRegistrationBean frb = new FilterRegistrationBean frb = new FilterRegistrationBean(filterX());
             // other config
             return verb;
        }
    }
}
```

This will only include the filter configuration when the condition is met, without duplication conditional instructions. This is also how Spring Boot registers filters, listeners etc. (See for instance how the [`DispatcherServlet` is registered](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.java#L77)).

Comment: This won't work because I won't be able to autowire. In your terminology, `FilterX` can't have things autowired into it. That's why I needed to use the hybrid solution I described in my question comment.

Comment: No you don't ... If it is a bean it will get things auto wired... If you create the filter inside the method which creates the filter registration it won't work, but if you create it as a bean it would work. The  key is you need to register both as `@Bean` not create one inside the method that creates the other. It has to be visible as a bean.

Comment: Ah right, I see. That makes sense in my head, but I'll test it out next week. Thanks for the suggestion!